# C++ unresolved external symbol LNK2019 and LNK2001

Tags: c++

I am implementing the shadow system found [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Dynamic_RTT_shadow_angles_in_Source_2007), I have made all the changes in clientshadowmgr.cpp, and added worldlight.cpp/.h to game/client.

When I build the solution, I get these errors:

```
1>clientshadowmgr.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall CWorldLights::GetBrightestLightSource(class Vector const &,class Vector &,class Vector &)" (?GetBrightestLightSource@CWorldLights@@QAE_NABVVector@@AAV2@1@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall CClientShadowMgr::UpdateShadowDirectionFromLocalLightSource(unsigned short)" (?UpdateShadowDirectionFromLocalLightSource@CClientShadowMgr@@AAEXG@Z)
1>clientshadowmgr.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class CWorldLights * g_pWorldLights" (?g_pWorldLights@@3PAVCWorldLights@@A)
1>.\Release_mod_hl2\\client.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

In worldlight.h:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Singleton exposure
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern CWorldLights *g_pWorldLights;
```

Not sure how to fix this, if anyone has any help, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Please post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code only.

Answer (score 0):

1) the files need to first be added as a separate project - a static library.

2) go to your

> project->rightclick->properties->Configuration
>   Properties->Linker->Additional dependencies

here add your lib file generated along with the path.

What you are seeing above is called [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)